# NVActivityIndicatorView not working on button press

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I have the following code for a button in my application to test my implementation of [NVActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView):

```
@IBAction func goButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.startAnimatingActivityIndicator()
    sleep(2)
    self.stopAnimatingActivityIndicator()
}
```

The view controllers in my application also have this extension:

```
extension UIViewController: NVActivityIndicatorViewable {
    func startAnimatingActivityIndicator() {
        let width = self.view.bounds.width / 3
        let height = width
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        startAnimating(size, message: "Loading...", type: NVActivityIndicatorType.circleStrokeSpin)
    }

    func stopAnimatingActivityIndicator() {
        self.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

The loading animations work elsewhere in the same view controller (i.e., the `viewDidLoad()` function) but for some reason I'm unable to get the loading animation to work on this button. The button is connected correctly as the application does sleep for the appropriate amount of time, but the loading animations fail to run.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The Indicator won't spin because the main thread is asleep. Use a 2 second timer to turn off the spinning instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Indicator won't spin because the main thread is asleep. Use a 2 second timer to turn off the spinning instead.

Answer (score 1):

@FryAnEgg coming in with the solution! The `sleep(2)` was preventing the loading animations from running.

Here's my updated code:

```
@IBAction func goButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.startAnimatingActivityIndicator()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) {
        self.stopAnimatingActivityIndicator()
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Will resubmit comment as answer so it can be selected. Good luck!